# Possible conflict issue in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I am trying to narrow down my issue but i'm at the point where I need to post my problem now!

I have code that when you click on an a tag, an div will appear, here is an example of mine.

```
<div class="row bottom-buffer">
    <a href="#" class="person">Teste, Man</a>
</div>
<div class="contactInfo well-sm custom-well">
    <!-- lots of content loaded from an external page (development_fetch.php) -->
</div>
```

with following jQuery:

```
j$('.person').click(function(e) {
    j$(this).closest('.row').next().slideToggle();
});
```

What this code does, is when you click on a persons name e.g Teste, Man, the contents of .contactInfo will display. It was working before, but due to enormous amounts of people, I recently had to implement pagination, further down the javascript I have this code:

```
j$("#results").load("development_fetch.php", {'page':0}, function() {
            j$("#1-page").addClass('active');
        });  
j$(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {
            j$("#results").empty(); 
            j$("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/assets/loader.gif" /></div>');
            var clicked_id = j$(this).attr("id").split("-"); 
            var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); 
            j$('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); 
            j$("#results").load("development_fetch.php", {'page': (page_num-1)}, function(){
            });
            j$(this).addClass('active'); 
            return false; 
        });
```

I'm unsure if the return false in the pagination code is preventing the a.person from performing as it should. I tried removing it but got nowhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

note - contents of .contactInfo is loaded from an external page.
note - if I type in to console `j$(".person").closest('.row').next().slideToggle();` it works fine.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't mention that, I get no errors in my console, I get this warning event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: @akira everyone using jQuery gets that error. Don't worry about that.

Comment: @DanielLisik I gathered as much, which is why I haven't worried too much about it lol

Comment: Also, in console if I type in to console j$(".person").closest('.row').next().slideToggle() it works. I don't understand!

Comment: Is that `.person` element outputted on page load by the server or created dynamically?

Comment: @Popnoodles It is created dynamically, when you click for example page 2, the pagination code uses the .load() to load an external page which has the .person element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
j$("#results").load("development_fetch.php",...
```

^ This is creating elements that didn't exist when this jQuery was executed:

```
j$('.person').click(function(e) {
    j$(this).closest('.row').next().slideToggle();
});
```

The elements it adds don't know about that instruction.

You need to bind the click to the closest ancestor that **does** exist and isn't overwritten, which is `#results`, but delegate the event to `.person` using `.on()` in the following way:

```
j$('#results').on('click', '.person', function(e) {
    j$(this).closest('.row').next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Mate, you're a freakin' genius. You get a beer if we ever meet. Is there any chance on you elaborating on the term binding? I see it works but I want to fully understand it because I know it will happen throughout the site i'm working on

Comment: Binding isn't the term in question, it's delegation.  This explains it well enough http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ - the important point is that whnever JS runs, it only binds/attaches to what exists at the time.

Comment: I like that, that makes sense, Thanks heaps!

Comment: Just for further clarification, because this one always catches people out, the difference is that your original jQ was saying "when `.person` is clicked run this function on it". When you add more `.person`s, those new elements don't know that instruction. When you click an element, the click event "bubbles up", which means its ancestors are clicked too, all the way up to `document`. The new jQ says "when `#results` is clicked and `.person` was the actual target run this function on the target". `#results` is never overwritten so always knows that instruction.